# OPENCV : I need to get coordinate whan I click

Tags: c, opencv

I newbie

```
void save(int event,int x,int y,int flags,void* firstImage){
    IplImage* pic = (IplImage*)firstImage;
    if(event==CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
        printf("%d--%d\n",x,y);
    }
    return( x, y);
}

void main(){
    IplImage* firstImage = cvLoadImage("first.jpg");    
    cvNamedWindow("First");
    cvSetMouseCallback("First",save,(void*)firstImage);
    cvShowImage("First",firstImage);
    CvRect pixel = cvRect(x,y,350,350);
    cvSetImageROI (first,pixel);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&firstImage);        
}
```

how I get coordinate form "save function" to use set x,y in ROI

Comment: You can move the part of the code in the main function that uses x and y to the save function.

Comment: in my code the save function can't return x,y to main function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a callback function because you do not know when the mouse click event will occur. There are various ways to get the values, the easiest one by using global variables (shown). A better but harder way is to pass as parameter **a pointer to a cvPoint that will be modified by your "save" function (NOT shown) instead of a "void* firstImage".**

The simplest solution that ought to work would be to define a global variable and to poll it until it has changed. Let me suggest this:

```
int GlobalX = -1; //These two variables will hold new information
int GlobalY = -1;

void save(int event,int x,int y,int flags,void* firstImage){
    IplImage* pic = (IplImage*)firstImage;
    if(event==CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
        printf("%d--%d\n",x,y);
        GlobalX = x; // Pass the coordinates to a scope visible to the main thread
        GlobalY = y;
    }
}

void main(){
    IplImage* firstImage = cvLoadImage("first.jpg");    
    cvNamedWindow("First");
    cvSetMouseCallback("First",save,(void*)firstImage);
    cvShowImage("First",firstImage);
    while (GlobalX == -1 && GlobalY == -1) cvWaitKey(100); // Wait until the user has clicked on the picture
    cvDestroyWindow("First"); // make sure that GlobalX and GlobalY will not be modified by the user anymore - important
    CvRect pixel = cvRect(GlobalX,GlobalY,350,350); // Use the coordinates.
    cvSetImageROI (first,pixel);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&firstImage);        
}
```

Comment: thank s lot for this solution It's solv >> cvSetImageROI (first,pixel) =cvSetImageROI (firstImage,pixel) right?  , but I have some question I want to use (GlobalX and GlobalY) at center  coordinate (in cvSetImageROI (GlobalX and GlobalY) is top left coordinate) how can I do that ?